# Azure Cosmos DB - count nested keys in subdocument

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Having a Cosmos DB document with below schema:

```
{
  id: 1,
  nested: {
    key1: true,
    key2: false
  }
}
```

Is there any SQL operator I could use to count the keys in the "nested" subdocument? Similar  to `Object.keys(nested).length` in JavaScript

Comment: You can do aggregates on enbedded arrays using Cosmos NoSQL query language, including using filter predicates. Can find an example of that here, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/query/object-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write Cosmos Db UDF to get count of nested keys document.

I have tried using sample data posted in question.

**UDF Code**

```
function getLength(nested) {
return  Object.keys(nested).length;
}
```

**Query to consume UDF**

```
SELECT udf.getLength(c.nested) AS LengthOfKeys FROM c
```

Here is [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRkm5.png) of the above query.

**Sample data**

```
{
"id": "1",
"nested": {
"key1": true,
"key2": false
}
{
"id": "2",
"nested": {
"key1": true,
"key2": false,
"key3": "hello"
}
```

Comment: I started thinking about a trigger which will update another field but I think UDF makes more sense, thank you @RitikaNalwaya